# Margin in pdf generated in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pdfkit

I have an ntml file that I want to save to pdf on Ubuntu. Locally on Macos I do this with

```
def generate_pdf(filename):
    file_read = settings_reports.path_ac + 'html/' + filename + '.html'
    file_write = settings_reports.path_ac + 'pdf/' + filename + '.pdf'
    options = {
        'page-size': 'A3', 'orientation': 'portrait',
        'margin-left': '20mm', 'margin-top': '20mm'
    }
    pdfkit.from_file(file_read, file_write, options=options_tc)
```

and `margin-left` with `margin-top` works correctly.

On ubuntu, I add the line to the function

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
```

and use it like `configuration=config` in `pdfkit.from_file()`.

But in the pdf generated on ubuntu, there are no indents at all, the html starts from the upper left corner. I tried to change the parameters in the `options` that I read about in the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/), but nothing helped.

Tell me please how to solve this?

Comment: Some suggestions: check version of `wkhtmltopdf`, use absolute paths.

Comment: @Memristor latest version, absolute path in docker container. nothing changed